# Loading data into Azure Synapse Analytics from Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am followin this tutorial to move data from SQL to Azure Synapse https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory

However, once I get to step 5c I cannot select a a Database name, Do I have to create an Azure Synapse Database first to copy data over there? I though that is what this tutorial will do?

I have a SQL database and I want to move the data into Azure Synapse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in Azure data factory your source and sink needs to be already present w.r.t database scenarios.
So it is expected that you already have an Azure SQL database and Azure SQL datawarehouse in place before proceeding with copy activity